# what is mean this syntax using numpy.mean with condition

Tags: python, numpy

```
result = map(lambda x: (x>0).mean(), np.array([[1,3], [2,4], [3,5]]))
print result
## output: [1.0, 1.0, 1.0]
```

what is mean of (x>0) condition in this syntax, and why do i get result like [1.0, 1.0, 1.0] ?

additional) If i use (x>0).mean((1,2)), what is mean of this (1,2)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`np.array([1, 3]) > 0` gives an array of boolean, each element saying whether an element of the original array was positive or not.

`np.mean` will give an arithmetic average of the array. However, it can only handle floats, so it coerces the booleans to floats. `float(True)` is `1.0`; `float(False)` is `0.0`.

Thus, `(x > 0).mean()` is the fraction of elements of `x` that are positive. For `[1,3]`, `[2,4]` and `[3,5]` it happens to be 100% in each case, or `1.0`. For `[-1, 0, 1]`, it would be `1/3`.

Answer (score 0):

> np.array > 0  return np.array of same shape but filled with boolean
>   value which satisfy the given condition and if you take mean then true
>   treated as 1.0 and false treated as 0 hence you got mean like 1.0 1.0.